# How to read contents of file using file path in javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

I have full path of file e.g "D:\File\1.xml" and want to read contents of it in javascript.
I tried using File and FileReader API's but no success. Following piece of code I tried.

```
var path = "D:\File\1.xml";
var file = new File(path); //Doesn't work
var fileReader = new FileReader(file); //filereader expects file object
```

Can anyone help out how to read local files from file path in javascript or how to create File object successfuly from path.
Thanks

Comment: In few words, you can't do that from a browser. You can ask the user to upload the file using the `<input type="file"/>` element, and use the File API to read it then (before the actual upload), but you can't do it given a file path, from the browser. See [Reading file contents on the client-side in javascript in various browsers](//stackoverflow.com/q/750032) for information on using the upload approach.